# Cookie share between sub domains

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, cookies, kentico

I have implemented cookie sharing between sub domains of my sites, but the issue is that not all cookies are shared. why this happens. Is there any cookie configuration that cookie becomes specific to site and could not be shared?

Answer (score 1):

- You should be able to share the cookie by using a domain in format of
  ".domain.com" (dot and root domain) and your "path=/" always.
- Double check that whenever you generate a cookie, you follow this rule.

Comment: I have provided in my web config and cookie is being set by kentico cms, i am able to access authentication cookie on subdomains but not the one for shopping cart

Comment: I would suggest you add more information in your question to display your Kentico settings/web.settings, Kentico version, the different cookies you are observing while debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Open inspector in Chrome -> switch to Application -> Cookies and see your cookies with all parameters. Make sure path, domain and http properties are correct.

Comment: yes, i saw that and the cookie which i am able to share contains HTTP checked and which are not shared are not checked. what this indicate?

Comment: If the HttpOnly flag (optional) is included in the HTTP response header, the cookie cannot be accessed through client side script (again if the browser supports this flag). As a result, even if a cross-site scripting (XSS) flaw exists, and a user accidentally accesses a link that exploits this flaw, the browser (primarily Internet Explorer) will not reveal the cookie to a third party.